# PyQt5 - button in second window is not doing action on click

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello I have 2 python files:

first one is called 'first.py', second is 'second.py':

My program is supposed to guide the user from first window to second window.

The problem is, the first window's button work fine when clicked. But in the second window, the buttons don't work even though they are "connected" to a function.

first.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QLineEdit
import sys
from second import Ui_second



              

class Ui_mainwindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainwindow):
        mainwindow.setObjectName("mainwindow")
        mainwindow.resize(1039, 717)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainwindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        

        self.nextbutton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)


        self.nextbutton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 380, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.nextbutton1.setFont(font)
        self.nextbutton1.setObjectName("nextbutton1")
        self.patientinfo_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.patientinfo_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 230, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.patientinfo_label.setFont(font)
        self.patientinfo_label.setObjectName("patientinfo_label")

        self.lastname_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 270, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lastname_label.setFont(font)
        self.lastname_label.setObjectName("lastname_label")
        self.lastname_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 278, 150, 20))
        self.lastname_input.setObjectName("lastname_input")
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)

        self.firstname_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.firstname_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 300, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.firstname_label.setFont(font)
        self.firstname_label.setObjectName("firstname_label")
      
        

        self.telephone_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.telephone_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 330, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.telephone_label.setFont(font)
        self.telephone_label.setObjectName("telephone_label")

        self.welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.welcome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 471, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.welcome.setFont(font)
        self.welcome.setObjectName("welcome")
        self.lastname_input_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_input_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 308, 150, 20))
        self.lastname_input_2.setObjectName("lastname_input_2")
        self.lastname_input_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_input_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 338, 150, 20))
        self.lastname_input_3.setObjectName("lastname_input_3")
        self.nextbutton1_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nextbutton1_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 380, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.nextbutton1_2.setFont(font)
        self.nextbutton1_2.setObjectName("nextbutton1_2")
        mainwindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainwindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainwindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainwindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainwindow)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input, self.lastname_input_2)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input_2, self.lastname_input_3)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input_3, self.nextbutton1)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.nextbutton1, self.nextbutton1_2)

        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input_3.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        self.nextbutton1.clicked.connect(self.clicked1)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainwindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainwindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainwindow", "VeriMed Tech"))
        self.nextbutton1.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Next"))
        self.patientinfo_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Patient Information"))
        self.lastname_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Last name:"))
        self.firstname_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "First name:"))
        self.telephone_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Telephone:"))
        self.welcome.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Welcome to VeriMed Technologies"))
        self.nextbutton1_2.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Exit"))


    def clicked1(self):
        print("passed first clicked test")
    
        mainwindow.close()
        ui = Ui_second()
        ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
        mainwindow.show()




        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_mainwindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

second.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QLineEdit
import sys



class Ui_second(object):
    
    def setupUi(self, second):
        second.setObjectName("second")
        second.resize(1039, 717)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(second)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lastname_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.imagelabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.imagelabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 250, 201, 141))
        self.imagelabel.setText("")
        self.imagelabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("databases/images/cartoon.png"))
        self.imagelabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.imagelabel.setWordWrap(False)
        self.imagelabel.setObjectName("imagelabel")
        self.lastname_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 275, 200, 30))
        self.lastname_input.setObjectName("lastname_input")
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 430, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.next.setFont(font)
        self.next.setObjectName("next")
        self.patientinfo_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.patientinfo_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 230, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.patientinfo_label.setFont(font)
        self.patientinfo_label.setObjectName("patientinfo_label")
        self.barcode_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.barcode_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 270, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.barcode_label.setFont(font)
        self.barcode_label.setObjectName("barcode_label")
        self.medication_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.medication_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 320, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.medication_label.setFont(font)
        self.medication_label.setObjectName("medication_label")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.welcome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 471, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.welcome.setFont(font)
        self.welcome.setObjectName("welcome")
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 430, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.exit.setFont(font)
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.medreal_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.medreal_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 323, 200, 30))
        self.medreal_label.setObjectName("medreal_label")
       
        second.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(second)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        second.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(second)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second)
        second.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input, self.next)
        second.setTabOrder(self.next, self.exit)

        self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked2)
        self.next.clicked.connect(self.clicked2)

    def retranslateUi(self, second):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second.setWindowTitle(_translate("second", "MainWindow"))
        self.next.setText(_translate("second", "Next"))
        self.patientinfo_label.setText(_translate("second", "Medication"))
        self.barcode_label.setText(_translate("second", "Barcode:"))
        self.medication_label.setText(_translate("second", "Medication:"))
        
        self.welcome.setText(_translate("second", "Scan medication"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("second", "Exit"))
        self.medreal_label.setText(_translate("second",""))
        
    def clicked2(self):        
        print("passed clicked 2test")
```

Comment: Do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but create another class that inherits 
from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

I suggest you to carefully read the official guidelines about using Designer, and remember to never edit the output of pyuic
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

Comment: can you clarify what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify the code generated by `Qt Designer` but create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

I suggest you to carefully read the official guidelines about using `Designer`, and remember to never edit the output of `pyuic`
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QLineEdit

#from second import Ui_second
class Ui_second(object):
    def setupUi(self, second):
        second.setObjectName("second")
        second.resize(1039, 717)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(second)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lastname_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.imagelabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.imagelabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 250, 201, 141))
        self.imagelabel.setText("")
        self.imagelabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("databases/images/cartoon.png"))
        self.imagelabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.imagelabel.setWordWrap(False)
        self.imagelabel.setObjectName("imagelabel")
        self.lastname_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 275, 200, 30))
        self.lastname_input.setObjectName("lastname_input")
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 430, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.next.setFont(font)
        self.next.setObjectName("next")
        self.patientinfo_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.patientinfo_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 230, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.patientinfo_label.setFont(font)
        self.patientinfo_label.setObjectName("patientinfo_label")
        self.barcode_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.barcode_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 270, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.barcode_label.setFont(font)
        self.barcode_label.setObjectName("barcode_label")
        self.medication_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.medication_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 320, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.medication_label.setFont(font)
        self.medication_label.setObjectName("medication_label")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.welcome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 471, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.welcome.setFont(font)
        self.welcome.setObjectName("welcome")
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 430, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.exit.setFont(font)
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.medreal_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.medreal_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 323, 200, 30))
        self.medreal_label.setObjectName("medreal_label")
       
        second.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(second)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        second.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(second)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second)
        second.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input, self.next)
        second.setTabOrder(self.next, self.exit)

#        self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked2)
#        self.next.clicked.connect(self.clicked2)

    def retranslateUi(self, second):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second.setWindowTitle(_translate("second", "MainWindow"))
        self.next.setText(_translate("second", "Next"))
        self.patientinfo_label.setText(_translate("second", "Medication"))
        self.barcode_label.setText(_translate("second", "Barcode:"))
        self.medication_label.setText(_translate("second", "Medication:"))
        
        self.welcome.setText(_translate("second", "Scan medication"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("second", "Exit"))
        self.medreal_label.setText(_translate("second",""))
        
#    def clicked2(self):        
#        print("passed clicked 2test")
              

class Ui_mainwindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainwindow):
        mainwindow.setObjectName("mainwindow")
        mainwindow.resize(1039, 717)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainwindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.nextbutton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nextbutton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 380, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.nextbutton1.setFont(font)
        self.nextbutton1.setObjectName("nextbutton1")
        self.patientinfo_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.patientinfo_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 230, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.patientinfo_label.setFont(font)
        self.patientinfo_label.setObjectName("patientinfo_label")
        self.lastname_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 270, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lastname_label.setFont(font)
        self.lastname_label.setObjectName("lastname_label")
        self.lastname_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 278, 150, 20))
        self.lastname_input.setObjectName("lastname_input")
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)

        self.firstname_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.firstname_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 300, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.firstname_label.setFont(font)
        self.firstname_label.setObjectName("firstname_label")
        self.telephone_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.telephone_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 330, 100, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.telephone_label.setFont(font)
        self.telephone_label.setObjectName("telephone_label")

        self.welcome = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.welcome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 471, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.welcome.setFont(font)
        self.welcome.setObjectName("welcome")
        self.lastname_input_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_input_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 308, 150, 20))
        self.lastname_input_2.setObjectName("lastname_input_2")
        self.lastname_input_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lastname_input_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 338, 150, 20))
        self.lastname_input_3.setObjectName("lastname_input_3")
        self.nextbutton1_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.nextbutton1_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 380, 80, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.nextbutton1_2.setFont(font)
        self.nextbutton1_2.setObjectName("nextbutton1_2")
        mainwindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainwindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainwindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainwindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainwindow)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input, self.lastname_input_2)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input_2, self.lastname_input_3)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.lastname_input_3, self.nextbutton1)
        mainwindow.setTabOrder(self.nextbutton1, self.nextbutton1_2)

        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
        #self.lastname_input_3.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked)
#        self.nextbutton1.clicked.connect(self.clicked1)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainwindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainwindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainwindow", "VeriMed Tech"))
        self.nextbutton1.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Next"))
        self.patientinfo_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Patient Information"))
        self.lastname_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Last name:"))
        self.firstname_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "First name:"))
        self.telephone_label.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Telephone:"))
        self.welcome.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Welcome to VeriMed Technologies"))
        self.nextbutton1_2.setText(_translate("mainwindow", "Exit"))


#    def clicked1(self):
#        print("passed first clicked test")
#        mainwindow.close()
#        ui = Ui_second()
#        ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
#        mainwindow.show()


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_second):        
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.lastname_input.returnPressed.connect(self.clicked2)
        self.next.clicked.connect(self.clicked2) 

    def clicked2(self):        
        print("passed clicked 2test")
        
        # ...
        
        self.parent.show()
        self.hide()
        

class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainwindow):        
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.nextbutton1.clicked.connect(self.clicked1)  

    def clicked1(self):
        print("passed first clicked test")
    
        self.secondWindow = SecondWindow(self)
        self.secondWindow.show()
        self.hide()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    mainwindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_mainwindow()
#    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
#    mainwindow.show()

    w = FirstWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you S. Nick, you fixed my issues, I will look and see how to emulate this for the future windows. You deserve so much more praise than this :)